# Servlet bridge OSGi commandline console outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, osgi

I am writing an OSGi servlet bridge. In the deployment descriptor of the bridge servlet module, the value of the `commandline` param is set to `-console`:

```
<servlet id="bridge-ds">
   <servlet-class>org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>commandline</param-name>
      <param-value>-console</param-value>           
   </init-param>
   <!-- etc. -->
```

Where would I see this console on a running application server, e.g. Tomcat or WebSphere? Is this setting only relevant when the application server is launched from Eclipse's Web Server Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define "-console 7272" in the commandline param value, then you can connect to the OSGI console using a simple telnet client on 7272 port. Be aware, that by default there is no authentication, so do not use this in production.

See https://eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php

Comment: Wunderbar! Thanks a million